# Android compose animation given by custom function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

As a side project I am making a small android app with jetpack compose. I would like to animate an offset of an image according with preset mathematical functions, let's take `f(x) = exp(x)` and `f(x) = \sin(x)` as basic examples. I just can't work out how to do this! Essentially I want to build my own animationspec I think... Can someone supply a basic example for me to look at?

One obvious approach is to animate a float value linearly and then define a new state as the function of this float. But this means calculating a value on each frame - I don't know if this is the best approach. What do you think?

[The animation documentation is so api heavy - it's great if you want a spring or tween animation spec but not obvious what to do if you want something outside of that. I started looking in the source code but it is very convoluted and I am still unclear how to approach my very simple question...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom easing and use it with tween like this:

```
val myCustomEasing = Easing { x ->
    return@Easing when (x) {
        0f -> 0f
        1f -> 1f
        else -> exp(x)      // your custom mathematical function
    }
}

val offsetY: Float by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = if (visible) 0f else 150f,
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = myCustomEasing), label = ""
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I want. I will test it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the rememberInfiniteTransition function to create an infinite animation loop.

```
import androidx.compose.animation.core.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.layoutId
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import kotlin.math.exp
import kotlin.math.sin

@Composable
fun CustomAnimationScreen() {
    var animatedValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

    val animationSpec = remember {
        infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0f,
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            )
        )
    }

    animatedValue = animationSpec.value

    val expOffset = remember { calculateExpOffset(animatedValue) }
    val sinOffset = remember { calculateSinOffset(animatedValue) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        // Animate an image with the calculated offsets
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .graphicsLayer(
                    translationX = expOffset.dp.toPx(),
                    translationY = sinOffset.dp.toPx()
                )
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun calculateExpOffset(animatedValue: Float): Float {
    // Modify this function to define your custom animation logic
    return (exp(animatedValue) - 1) * 100
}

@Composable
fun calculateSinOffset(animatedValue: Float): Float {
    // Modify this function to define your custom animation logic
    return (sin(animatedValue * 2 * Math.PI) * 50).toFloat()
}
```